# Rails simple_from: specify model id in input id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Simple Form generates by default id for inputs in form some this way id="#{model_name}_#{attr_name}".

I need to include id of model in this input id, because i have several forms of models on single page (nested). So id would be like id="#{model_name}_#{model_ID}_#{attr_name}"

By example

```
= simple_form_for([@site, supply]) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  ...
```

Generates form like it:

```
<form ... id="edit_supply_4">
  <input ... id="supply_name" ... >
```

But i need this:

```
<form ... id="edit_supply_4">
  <input ... id="supply_4_name" ... >
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a `input_html` hash allows you to customise the attributes of the input:

```
= simple_form_for([@site, supply]) do |f|
  = f.input :name, :input_html => {
    :id => "#{@site.model_name}_#{@site.id}_name"
  }
```

Comment: Could you please consider adding an explanation to your code?

Comment: Of course. But i want to avoid adding id to each input manually. Maybe is there some way to fix it globally?